# Use of Semicolon in this Sentence

Tags: punctuation, semicolons

In the following sentence can the first comma be replaced with a semicolon for smoother reading?

> "An hour drifted by, and the lady, whose name was Arcey Pierre, called it a day."

Comment: If you want to replace ", and" with a semicolon, yes ("An hour drifted by; the lady, whose name...). Otherwise, no ("An hour drifted by; and the lady, whose name...).

Comment: @AleksandrH, that sounds like an answer. Post it?

Comment: @MathieuK. Nah, it's fine.

Comment: @Mathiu K I adapted an edit; the previous reason was carried over. '... had begun to call it a day' treats a punctive statement as durative.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth: yeah, I thought that was weird. I assume the OP meant something along the lines of "was more and more inclined to call it a day" or "began to pack up her things".

Comment: @Mathiu K Positively mellifluous. You should write for films.

Comment: Having reread the question, it seems off-topic: what is "smoother reading" is opinion-based. As for Grammar Monster's statement that the use of conjunctions immediately after a semicolon is "outdated", one asks "so what?" What was once in style becomes out-of-style, what was out-of-style becomes in  style again... the author should choose his own punctuation usage based on his own sense of style.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can. And there is no inherent reason you must, or have to, delete the *and* (coordinating conjunction) right after the semicolon any more than there is a rational rule that says you can't [start a sentence with *and*](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/16976/using-and-at-the-beginning-of-a-sentence).

So yes,

> "An hour drifted by; and the lady, whose name was Arcey Pierre, called it a day.

is fine. See this [highly upvoted answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/20760/210913) (+14 and climbing) regarding the usage of the coordinating conjunction *but* right after a semicolon.

As for Grammar Monster's statement that the use of conjunctions immediately after a semicolon is "outdated", one asks "so what?" What was once "in style" becomes out-of-style; and what was out-of-style becomes in style again... the author should choose her/his own punctuation usage based on her/his own sense of style.

Having reread the question, I think it is off-topic'; for what is "smoother reading" is opinion-based.

Comment: I'd say 'When a conjunction (words like and, but and or) is used to merge two independent clauses into one sentence, it is possible to use a semicolon before the conjunction to outrank any commas in the clause. (This practice is acceptable, but it is considered outdated these days. However, if you think a semicolon makes your sentence clearer, you can use one.)' (even if from [GrammarMonster](http://www.grammar-monster.com/lessons/semicolons_before_conjunctions.htm)) is a rational guideline.

Comment: Commas and semicolons aren't treated like various forms of parentheses in mathematics. One comma before the conjunction and two to frame a non-essential relative. Those are the relevant rules. In a short sentence like this, with no possibility of falsely parsing it, the semicolon is overkill.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going another way on this one: put a period after "by" and drop the "and".

> "An hour drifted by. The lady, whose name was Arcey Pierre, called it a day."

In fairness, whether you go with a period or a semicolon here will depend on the surrounding text. See AleksandrH's input for the way to use the semicolon.

Comment: This is possibly the better solution, but does not address OP's actual question.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth: true. Let me CW-post AleksandrH's answer, which is probably closest to the standard approach.

Answer (score 0):

[AleksandrH](https://english.stackexchange.com/users/147283/aleksandrh) [said in the comments](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/444077/use-of-semicolon-in-this-sentence/444095?noredirect=1#comment1067081_444077)

> If you want to replace ", and" with a semicolon, yes ("An hour drifted by; the lady, whose name...). Otherwise, no ("An hour drifted by; and the lady, whose name...).

As to the acceptability of the semicolon, [GrammarMonster](http://www.grammar-monster.com/lessons/semicolons_before_conjunctions.htm) (often better than the name warrants) has:

> When a conjunction (words like *and*, *but* and *or*) is used to merge
>   two independent clauses into one sentence, *it is possible* to use a
>   semicolon before the conjunction to outrank any commas in the clause.
>   (This practice is acceptable, but it is considered outdated these
>   days. However, if you think a semicolon makes your sentence clearer,
>   you can use one.)

[emphasis partly EA]

The article also adds examples from respected sources, but not recent ones. The Rebecca West quotation is possibly the most recent, dating from 1937.